# How to correctly print:

Tags: python

I am trying to teach myself python using interactivepython.org. I have come across a problem that I can not figure out. I have the slope and the spacing correct. I need it to print one less number every time. Could anybody help a newbie out?...

My Code:

```
for j in range(11):

    for i in range(j):

        print(str(i), end=" ")

    print()

    print("")
```

Output:

```
0 

0 1 

0 1 2 

0 1 2 3 

0 1 2 3 4 

0 1 2 3 4 5 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Desired Output:

```
10

11 12

13 14 15

16 17 18 19

20 21 22 23 24

25 26 27 28 29 30

31 32 33 34 35 36 37

38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45

46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54
```

The exercise is about nesting for loops...I know there are other ways to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
start = 10
width = 9
for i in range(1, width+1):
    for _ in range(i):
        print (start, end=" ")
        start += 1
    print('\n')
```

**Output:**

```
10 

11 12 

13 14 15 

16 17 18 19 

20 21 22 23 24 

25 26 27 28 29 30 

31 32 33 34 35 36 37 

38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 

46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54
```

Comment: Thanks that is just about identical to what I came up with. I always feel like I answer my own question after I ask it lol. Thank you to everyone though! All great answers. I did however need to print a blank line in between did I do this the best way?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
current, levels = 10, 9
for i in range(levels):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        print(current, end = " ")
        current += 1
    print("\n")
```

**Output**

```
10

11 12

13 14 15

16 17 18 19

20 21 22 23 24

25 26 27 28 29 30

31 32 33 34 35 36 37

38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45

46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> lst = list(range(54,9, -1))
>>> for j in range(11):
...     for i in range(j):
...         if len(lst):
...             print(lst.pop(), end=" ")
...     print(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this one again for you Brandon Shockley :)

code:

```
x = 9
lines = 10
for i in range(lines):
    for j in range(i):
       x+=1
       print x,
    print ''
```

output:

```
10 
11 12 
13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 
25 26 27 28 29 30 
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 
38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 
46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 5
```

Hope This helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
inc = 10

for j in range(10):

    for i in range(j):

        print(inc, end=" ")
        inc += 1


    print()

    print("")
```

Is anything wrong with this?

Comment: It works I was more curious if I am breaking any best practices by incrementing in a loop or some other reason this isnt the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Single loop, in Python 2.x (can't remove the space after each print)

```
c = 1
j = 0
for i in range(10, 55):
  print str(i) + ',',
  j += 1
  if j == c:
    print
    c += 1
    j = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `join`

```
start = 10
for i in range(1, 10):
    print(' '.join(map(str, range(start, start + i))))
    start += i
```

A pointlessly compact version using `join` and some maths:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, 
    range(10 + i * (i+1) / 2, 10 + (i+1) * (i+2) / 2))) for i in range(9)))
```

And confusingly, this also works (in python 2):

```
j = 9
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(j + 1, j + i + 1):
        print j, 
    print
```